# arduino, error: invalid operands of types 'char [14]' and 'char [5]' to binary 'operator+'

Tags: arduino

I have a problem with some code.
Have read a tons of topics, but most are them are related to custom libraries.

My code is not related to any custom libraries.
I hope some of you know what im doing wrong.
I'm simply trying to "merge" two strings into a new variable.

Error:

```
sketch_SS01:13: error: invalid operands of types 'char [14]' and 'char [5]' to binary 'operator+'
char apiPath = apiPage + pid;
                      ^
exit status 1
invalid operands of types 'char [14]' and 'char [5]' to binary 'operator+'
```

Error related to this code:

```
// api details
char apiPage[] = "/api.php?pid=";
char pid[] = "8855";
char apiPath = apiPage + pid;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler says it: you cannot use `operator+` to concatenate C strings (i.e. `char[]`). You need to use the library function `strcat` or it's safer sibling `strncat`.

The concatenation of a string `x` onto the string `dest` is `strcat (dest,x);` but please consult the documentation and pay extra attention to the risk of buffer overflows when dealing with char arrays.

To write your example as it is written you can do

```
// api details
char apiPage[] = "/api.php?pid=";
char pid[] = "8855";
char apiPath[100] = ""; // make sure it' long enough and initialized to empty string 
strcat(apiPath, apiPage);
strcat(apiPath, pid);
```

or you could copy the strings using to the correct place in the destination string using`strcpy` or `strncpy`.

**Addition:**

A (perhaps better/simpler/safer) alternative is to use the `String` class which has all the expected string functionality (like constructors, add, append, etc.): see https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject

Comment: Thanks, that worked great. But why do they not work as global variables? It only works if I put it inside the setup() or loop() functions/scope.

Comment: what doesn't work? BTW I just updated my answer with a reference to the 'proper' string class as an alternative to `char[]`

Comment: To clarify my "what doesn't work?" I would expect it to work as global variables as well, unless for some reason the global variable ends up in read-only memory. (But I haven't done that on an arduino.) How do you declare the non-working global variables? And what is the problem? Compiler error or wrong behaviour?